# Is at least one of $6k + 1$ or $6k-1$ prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

We know that any prime number ( $> 2,3$) can be written in the form $6k+1$ or $6k-1$. Is it necessary that at least one of $6k+1$ or $6k-1$ is a prime number ?

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Note that $119$ is not prime, and neither is $121$. There are infinitely many others. If $n$ is very large, it becomes very likely that neither $6n-1$ nor $6n+1$ is prime. This is a consequence of the Prime Number Theorem.

Comment: Spend at least five minutes trying yourself... k= 20, 24, 31, 34, 36, 41, 48, 50, 54, 57, 69, 71, 79, 86, 88, 89, 92, 97, 104, 106...

Comment: arbitrarily long gaps in primes, $\{n!+k : 2\le k\le n\}$ has no primes for any $n$.

Comment: Good advice if you don't know a lot about prime numbers is that propositions that "easily" characterizes prime numbers tend to be false. It's better to strive for finding counterexamples instead of trying to prove it right away.

Comment: **"We know that any prime number $( >2,3)$ can be written in the form $6k+1$ or $6k−1$."** - I don't know. Can anybody give me a quick proof?

Comment: @pushpen.paul All the classes $\pmod 6$ are $0, 1, 2, 3, -2, -1$. No prime can be divisble by $6$, or be divisible by $2$ or be divisible by $3$ hence a prime is either $1$ or $-1$ modulo $6$.

Answer (score 10):

No, take $k=20$ for example:

- $6k-1=119=7\cdot17$
- $6k+1=121=11\cdot11$

As a side note, if the answer to your question was yes, then it would imply that the total amount of prime numbers is somewhere between $\displaystyle\frac{1}{6}$ of all positive integers to $\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}$ of all positive integers.

Answer (score 8):

No, for lots of reasons:

- There are arbitrarily long sequences of composite numbers. In fact, to construct a sequence of length at least $N - 1$, consider $N! + 2, ..., N! + N$. Letting $N$ be at least $9$ guarantees that this is very false.
- A counterexample can be found by counting for a while.
- If this were true, it would guarantee that there are infinitely many prime gaps of size at most $8$. This would be a significant improvement on recent work by [Yitang Zhang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitang_Zhang).

Comment: It would also violate the prime number theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Constructing $k$ that are counter-examples is easy, by means of choosing what number should be a divisor of $6k-1$ and what number should be a divisor of $6k+1$.

If we decide to have $m | (6k-1)$ and $n \mid (6k+1)$, then that is the same thing as saying

$$ 6k \equiv 1 \pmod{m} $$
$$ 6k \equiv -1 \pmod{n} $$

As long as $m,n,6$ are all relatively prime, we can solve this system of equations for $k$; e.g. by using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: +1 but my inner nitpick wants to add that $\gcd(mn,6)=1$

Answer (score 0):

Any number must in in this series $6k-3,6k-2,6k-1,6k,6k+1,6k+2$

$k=1$ then
$3,4,5,6,7,8$

$k=2$ then
$9,10,11,12,13,14$

$k=3$ then
$15,16,17,18,19,20$

$k=4$ then
$21,22,23,24,25,26$

.

.

In that series, $6k-3,6k-2,6k,6k+2$

cannot be prime because they are composite numbers. $3(2k-1),2(3k-1),6k,2(3k+1))$

You have only 2 options for prime numbers. $6k-1$ or $6k+1$ but we do not know if they are prime numbers or not. We can only think that they are candidate for prime number. As barak manos pointed,

$k=20$ then
$117,118,119,120,121,122$

Our prime candidates in the form of $6k-1,6k+1$ are $119,121$ but both of them are composite numbers.

Answer (score 0):

No, because there are infinitely many twin composites in the twin arithmetic progressions 5,7+6n.